Preallocating an array to fake size increase
I am new to C and I understand that I cannot increase the size of an array once it's created.
If I knew in advance that my array would have a fixed maximum size, I would like to ask if it is a good idea to simply create an array with this maximum size and work only on the first N indexes (where N is the initial size I am interested to work with). Then, if I need to, I can "artificially" increase my array by (e.g.) working on the first N+Z indexes (where Z represents the amount by which my array needs to grow).
My aim is to store the coordinates of a snake game, where each coordinate represent a piece of my snake in either X or Y (would need two arrays for this).
I also know I should be accessing the array with pointers. Is this something reasonable for my case?

Suggestion for the array with snake coordinates: int coords[MAX_SNAKE][2]; // x in 0; y in 1

@pmg Or use an array of struct type.

This is what dynamic memory allocation (malloc) is for.  You can resize a dynamically allocated block of memory using realloc.

This technique will work, it's what programmers usually did before dynamic memory allocation became available. Whether it's a good idea depends on the specific circumstances.

Generally speaking, the question is too broad. It depends on how much data you need, how often you need to enlarge it, what OS you run this on, etc. Other languages where increasing array is easy, such as python, it is so because arrays are not really just arrays (a mix of array and chained lists). Sometimes this is the thing to do. Some OS/hardware allow address remapping, so that they can make appear contiguous addresses that are not physically contiguous. On such system, a realloc would almost always work (since, yes, in C, there is a call to increase array size).

Sometimes, it is indeed better to simply allocate in advance the arrray. In your case, for a snake game, first of all, that is only a few bytes. Less than the overhead of any smarter method. So, I really don't see any reason not to simply allocate the max size of the snake. Plus, anyway, avoid to allocate in advance may make sense when you only know that you MAY use that much memory, but also may never do so in the entire program life. In a snake game, chance are that you will reach that size. It is not like you want to let other programs to use that memory while you don't use it yet.


If I knew in advance that my array would have a fixed maximum size, I would like to ask if it is a good idea to simply create an array with this maximum size and work only on the first N indexes (where N is the initial size I am interested to work with). Then, if I need to, I can "artificially" increase my array by (e.g.) working on the first N+Z indexes (where Z represents the amount by which my array needs to grow).

Yes, generally speaking, this is a perfectly viable alternative when you have a known upper bound on the amount of space you will need.
If your upper bound were extremely large then there would be caveats, but I don't anticipate that a game such as yours would have needs of that size.

My aim is to store the coordinates of a snake game, where each coordinate represent a piece of my snake in either X or Y (would need two arrays for this).

That particular arrangement seems odd.  For a list of coordinates, I would be inclined to use an n x 2 (2D) array.  But the same general considerations apply.

I also know I should be accessing the array with pointers.

In C, you cannot avoid accessing an array via pointers, but most operations do not require you to be explicit about that.

Is this something reasonable for my case?

Overall, yes, at the level of detail you've given, what you describe seems reasonable.

Instead of using hardcoded arrays use dynamic memory allocation:
int *myArray = malloc(N * sizeof(*myArray);
if(myArray) 
{
     /* now you can use the memory*/
}

Then you can use allocated memory as an array:
myArray[5] = 100;

When you need more memory call realloc
int *tmp;
tmp = realloc(myArray, (N + Z) * sizeof(*myArray));
if(tmp) 
{
    myArray = tmp;
    /* you have new size of your array - old data is preserved if new size is larger than old */
}

When you do need it anymore free it:
free(myArray);


I didn't downvote, but this would be better if it explained that the OP's suggestion of just pre-allocating the largest space needed will work, but if they want an array to change in size at runtime, they'll need to use dynamically allocated memory.
